# Disable body scrolling on element

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I created a floating sticky bootstrap panel at the bottom right of the screen. It look like a chat support like [intercom](https://www.intercom.com/). When I'm scrolling on the panel the body will scroll too. And it's really weird when I'm scrolling on mobile because I display the panel in full screen and we can scroll on the body while the panel is in fullscreen.

So I put pieces of code in my JS to enable / disable the body scrollbar :

```
    if (...) {
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    } else {
        $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
    }
    ...
```

It works and it's overkill I think but I don't found better. But I have another problem. If I go on my mobile the chrome address bar will be hide when I scroll on the full screen panel and it's really ugly because the panel will be redrawed every time.

Do you know a better way to disable body scrolling when the cursor is on certain element (a magic css property ?) and disable auto hiding address bar of browsers ?

If you go on [intercom](http://disable%20auto%20hiding%20address%20bar) with your mobile it's exactly what I want.

Comment: Try adding your chat panel in Iframe, it will help you to avoid body scrolling.. For better understanding, can you please add a code or jsfiddle so that we can test it on mobile as well..

Comment: overflow-x for vertical scroll and overflow-y for horizontal scroll

Answer (score 0):

if you need to totally enable or disable scroll you must use this way:

```
if (...) {
    $('html, body').css({ overflow: 'hidden', height: '100%' }); // to hide
} else {
    $('html, body').css({ overflow: 'auto (or) scroll', height: 'auto' }); // to show
}
```

you must include html as just only body is not enough. Hope it helps.

Comment: This will not disable the auto hiding address bar